# Ubuntu 14.04.5LTS doesnt boot with Kernel 3.13.0-38-generic

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on my PC, which by default came with Kernel version 4.4.0-47-generic. For my working purpose I need only 3.13.0-98-generic. I installed the same, reloaded to grub and chose to boot with 3.13.0-98-generic kernel. But I see only a blank screen and it doesn't boot-up for ever.

I tried purging and re-installing the Kernel but didn't help. Any way to fix this or any other option to Boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel 3.13.0-98-generic. (These are the specific versions I require)

Comment: Why do you require an older kernel? May you add the results of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: I require it for a specific testing. The NIC card I'm testing supports only that kernel.   O/p taken from the last processor                                            processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v3 @ 3.50GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x37
cpu MHz         : 1200.253
cache size      : 10240 KB

Comment: Complete output: https://www.evernote.com/l/AKmZI8ZvOENORp44FrXRudf87sd8iQnYhck

Comment: Interestingly I'm able to bypass the blank screen by replacing "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" in the boot entry from the grub. But after that I'm getting a weird, low graphic screen from which I'm unable to recover. Have to do this every time I reload